# Duvida: lista dinâmica encadeada dentro de outra, em C

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou com uma enorme dificuldade para conseguir criar uma lista encadeada dinamicamente dentro de outra usando estrutura de dados e manipulala, pois não encontrei nada que exemplifica como criar uma lista dentro de outra. Sei criar uma unica lista dinâmica, porem não consigo criar outra dentro dela.

O que meu programa deve fazer:

Tenho uma lista de *Bandas*; cada *banda* é uma lista de *albuns*; e cada *album* é uma lista de *musica*. E no programa o usuário pode manipular musicas, albuns e bandas como quiser.

Meu codigo esta abaixo, porem não funciona. Alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

### Arquivo .C

```c
#include "biblioteca.h"

ElemM *lm;
ElemA *la;
ElemB *lb;
//---------------------------MAIN--------------------------------->

int main()
{
  lb = cria_lista_banda();
  la =  cria_lista_album();
  lm = cria_lista_musica();


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
} 
//----------------------------------------------------------------->

ElemB *cria_lista_banda(){
        ElemB *lb;
        lb =  malloc(sizeof(ElemB));
        lb->prox_banda = NULL;
        return lb;


}

ElemA *cria_lista_album(){
        ElemA *la;
        la =  malloc(sizeof(ElemA));
        la->prox_album= NULL;
        return la;


}

ElemM *cria_lista_musica(){
        ElemM *lm;
        lm =  malloc(sizeof(ElemM));
        lm->prox_musica= NULL;
        return lm;


}

int incluir_musica(ElemM *lm, ElemA *la, ElemB *lb, int id_m, int tempo, char *nome_m, int id_a, int id_b){
        int valor1, valor2, valor3, i;

        valor1 = busca_banda(id_b, lb);
        valor2 = busca_album(id_b, id_a, lb, la);
        valor3 = busca_musica(id_b, id_a, id_m, lb, la, lm);
        if(valor3 == -1) return -1;

        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor1; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor2; i++){
             p = p->prox_album;         
        }

        ElemM *novo, *novocpy;
        p->musicas_do_album->novo = malloc( sizeof(ElemM));
        novocpy = p->musica_do_album->novo;
        if(novo == NULL) return 0;
        novocpy->id_musica = id_m;
        novocpy->tempo_da_musica = tempo;
        strcpy(novocpy->nome_musica, nome_m);
        novocpy->prox_musica = lc->prox_musica;
        lm->prox_musica = novocpy;
        return 1;
}

int busca_banda(int id, ElemB *lb){
        int cont = 0;
        ElemB *p;
        p = lb->prox_banda;
        while(p != NULL && p->id_banda != id){
                p = p->prox_banda;
                cont++;
        }
        if(p == NULL) return -1;
        return cont;
}

int buscar_album(int id_b, int id_a, ElemB *lb, ElemR *la){
        int valor_busca = busca_banda(id_b, lb); 
        int i;
        int cont = 0;

        if(valor_busca == -1) return -1;
        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        while(p != NULL && p->id_album != id_a){
             p = p->prox_album;
             cont++;         
        }      

        if(p != NULL) return -1;
        return cont;   

}


int buscar_musica(int id_b, int id_a, int id_m, ElemB *lb, ElemA *la, ElemM *lm){
        int valor_busca1 = busca_banda(id_b, lb);
        int valor_busca2 = busca_album(id_b, id_a, lb, la); 
        int i;
        int cont = 0;

        if(valor_busca1 == -1) return -1;
        if(valor_busca2 == -1) return -1;
        ElemB *q;
        q = lb->prox_banda;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca1; i++){
              q = q->prox_banda;
        }
        ElemA *p;
        p = q->albuns_da_banda->prox_album;
        for(i = 0; i <= valor_busca2; i++){
             p = p->prox_album;         
        }
        ElemM *k;
        k = p->musica_do_album->prox_musica;
        while(k != NULL && k->id_musica != id_m){
             k = k->prox_musica;
             cont++;         
        }       

        if(k != NULL) return -1;
        return cont;   

}
```

### Arquivo .h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct musica{
       int id_musica;
       int tempo_musica;
       char nome_musica[30];
       struct musica *prox_musica;
       };      

typedef struct musica ElemM;

struct album{
       int id_album;
       char nome_album[30];
       struct musica *musica_do_album;
       struct album *prox_album;
       };

typedef struct album ElemA;

struct banda{
       int id_banda;
       char nome_banda[30];
       struct album *albuns_da_banda;
       struct banda *prox_banda;
       };       

typedef struct banda ElemB;


ElemB *cria_lista_banda();
ElemR *cria_lista_album();
ElemC *cria_lista_musica();
int incluir_musica(ElemM *lm, ElemA *la, ElemB *lb, int id_m, int tempo, char *nome_m, int id_a, int id_b)
int busca_banda(int id, ElemB *lb);
int buscar_album(int id_b, int id_a, ElemB *lb, ElemR *la);
int buscar_musica(int id_b, int id_a, int id_m, ElemB *lb, ElemA *la, ElemM *lm);
```

Comment: Os includes dos headers *normais* nao sao necessarios no `Arquivo .h`. Ficam melhor no `Arquivo .C`. Podes acrescentar pinclude guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) no `Arquivo .h`

Comment: Se você quer um programa para usar, e não fazer um programa para aprender C, você defintivamente deveria estar usando uma linguagem que abstraia coisas básicas como estruturas de dados. Você pode usar Python, Javascript, Ruby, PHP, e mesmo Java e se preocupar mais com o seu problema do que em como fazer as coisas básicas que C não faz.

Comment: Como assim, "não funciona" ? Você compilou o programa ? A compilação terminou sem erros ? Você rodou o programa ? Ele deu um resultado diferente do que você esperava ? Qual resultado você esperava e qual resultado deu ? O programa deu crash ? *I'm a doctor Jim, not a psychic!*

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente existe um erro em sua biblioteca.
Onde existe "struct casa" deveria ser "struct musica".

Esse erro ocorre em 3 lugares diferentes.

Comment: Já corrigi isso, mas esta dando erro na função incluir musica. Não estou conseguindo incluir nenhuma musica, não tenho certeza se o que fiz está logicamente correto.

Comment: A parece que não existe a struct novo não existe, e alem disso não sei se foi criado as lista de maneira correta.

Answer (score 0):

Olhe bem, você declarou 3 ponteiros, um pra cada tipo de lista. Não entendi a lógica nisso.

O que você deseja é provavelmente apenas um ponteiro para **Banda** (estou supondo que sempre que você for cadastrar um **Álbum** é preciso que você já tenha uma **Banda** para vinculá-lo e de maneira análoga, quando você for cadastrar uma **Música** já deve haver um **Álbum** para inserí-la, estou certo em supor isso?).

Com base nessa suposição acima, a função pra criar uma nova **Banda** deveria primeiro verificar se já existe alguma banda nessa **lista de Bandas**, e caso exista, em que posição você gostaria de inserí-la nessa lista?

Que tal iniciar seu programa com a **lista de Banda** NULL e alterar a função pra adicionar bandas conforme mostro abaixo?

Você inicializaria o ponteiro pra **lista de Banda** assim:

```
 ElemB *bandas = NULL;
```

Declararia a função pra registrar uma nova banda assim:

```
ElemB *adiciona_banda(Elemb *lista_de_bandas, int id, char* nome){
    ElemB *nova_banda;
    nova_banda =  (ElemB*) malloc(sizeof(ElemB));
    nova_banda->id_banda = id;
    strcpy(nova_banda->nome_banda, nome);
    nova_banda->prox_banda = lista_de_bandas; //Aqui eu tou inserindo a nova banda no inicio da lista
    nova_banda->albuns_da_banda = NULL; //supondo que toda banda é cadastrada antes dos albuns.
    return nova_banda;
}
```

e na hora de chamar na main:

```
  bandas = adiciona_banda(bandas, 1, "Ivete Sangalo");
  bandas = adiciona_banda(bandas, 2, "Papa Roach");
```

Observe que não foi feita nenhuma verificação de ID e NOME antes de adicionar (vai depender da sua lógica ai...)

Agora como adicionar um álbum? A função seria bem parecida:

```
ElemA *adiciona_album(ElemA* lista_de_albuns, int id, char * nome){
    ElemA *novo_album;
    novo_album = (ElemA*) malloc(sizeof(ElemA));
    novo_album->id_album = id;
    strcpy(novo_album->nome_album, nome);
    novo_album->prox_album = lista_de_albuns; // também adicionando o novo album no inicio da lista
    novo_album->musica_do_album = NULL; //SUpondo que o álbum deve ser cadastrado antes das músicas e portanto ele é criado vazio.
    return novo_album;
}
```

Suponha que você queira adicionar o **Álbum Infest** e o **Álbum LoveHateTragedy** na banda Papa Roach (que é a primeira da lista de bandas no exemplo):

```
  bandas->albuns_da_banda = cria_lista_album(bandas->albuns_da_banda, 1, "Infest");
  bandas->albuns_da_banda = cria_lista_album(bandas->albuns_da_banda, 2, "LoveHateTragedy");
```

Caso você quisesse adicionar o **Álbum O mundo vai** na banda Ivete...

```
  ElemB *p = bandas->prox_banda; //*p vai conter o endereço do Nó da Banda Ivete
  p->albuns_da_banda = cria_lista_album(p->albuns_da_banda, 1, "O mundo vai");
```

Mais uma vez, não estou fazendo verificação se **id** ou **nome** do álbum já existe.

A forma que você vai fazer com música é bem parecida:

```
  ElemM *adiciona_musica(ElemM* lista_de_musicas, int id, int tempo, char * nome){
       ElemM nova_musica* = (ElemM*) malloc (sizeof(ElemM));
       nova_musica->id_musica = id;
       nova_musica->tempo_musica = tempo;
       strcpy(nova_musica->nome_musica, nome);
       nova_musica->prox_musica = lista_de_musicas;
       return nova_musica;

  }
```

E supondo que queira adicionar a musica LoveHateTragedy ao álbum LoveHateTragedy da banda Papa Roach, a forma de chamar seria:

```
 ElemM *p = bandas->albuns_da_banda->musicas; //já sei que Papa Roach ta no inicio da lista e que LoveHateTragedy é o primeiro álbum...
 p = adiciona_musica(p, 1, "LoveHateTragedy");
```

Fazendo dessa forma... Recomendo alterar as funções de busca pra retornar um ponteiro (ou NULL caso não seja encontrado). Nesse exemplo eu usei as posições das bandas e álbuns que eu já sabia pra encurtar o exemplo. Vou deixar só o cabeçalho das funções de busca que eu utilizaria e a implementação fica pra você:

```
 //pra buscar a banda você pode passar tanto a variável bandas como parâmetro ou 
 //deixar sem passar por parâmetro, já que ela foi declarada como variável global.
 ElemB* busca_banda_por_id(int id);
 ElemB* busca_banda_por_nome(char *nome);

 //Aqui você precisa passar a lista de Álbuns que da banda que
 //encontrou na chamada de uma das buscas de banda como parâmetro.
 //Tome cuidado que a busca_banda pode retornar NULL, verifique isso antes de chamar
 //uma das 2 funções abaixo.
 ElemA* busca_album_por_id(ElemA* albuns_da_banda, int id); 
 ElemA* busca_album_por_id(ElemA* albuns_da_banda, char *nome);

 //E, de forma análoga, estariam as funções de buscar a musica
 ElemM* busca_musica_por_id(ElemM* musicas_do_album, int id);
 ElemM* busca_musica_por_id(ElemM* musicas_do_album, char *nome);
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, vamos por partes! Se você quiser criar uma biblioteca .h, você deve ter um arquivo .c sem função main, onde você terá todas as funções que existem nesse .h . Dessa forma, a main deve estar em um arquivo separado para ela, onde você incluirá a biblioteca .h que você criou.

Além disso, em C, se você quiser chamar a função A de dentro da função B, certifique-se de que a função A está posicionada em algum lugar do código acima da função B. É por isso que a main sempre deve ficar abaixo de todas as outras funções ;)

Por fim, você deve colocar os devidos includes (<stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>,<string.h> etc.) em todos os arquivos .c, tanto na main, quanto o .c referente ao .h.

Depois de arrumar essas coisas, acredito que se der mais algum erro, vai ser só probleminhas de código ou lógica mesmo! Boa sorte, qqr coisa tamo aí